# Maximum and minimum on unit circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

How would I do $f(x, y) =  5x^2 + 6y^2$ on circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$?

I understand that we first solve for the critical points getting $f(0, 0) = 0$ which is the global minimum. But after that how do we get the points at the boundary. I know $x = \arccos(\theta)$ and $y = \arcsin(\theta)$ but after putting those into our $f(x,y)$ I get confused when taking the derivative of that new function. Can anyone help or give a hint?

Comment: On the circle $x^2 + y^2=1$ you have $f(x, y) =  5x^2 + 6y^2=5+y^2$ which is minimised when $y=0$ (so $x=\pm 1$) and maximised when $y=\pm 1$ (so $x=0$)

Comment: $(0,0)$ is not a point on the circle $x^2 + y^2=1$ though it is a point in the disk $x^2 + y^2\le 1$

Comment: How did you go frrom $5x^2 + 6y^2$ to $5+ y^2$. Furthermore, can you find y = 0 algebraically from the start?

Comment: $5x^2 + 6y^2 = 5(x^2 + y^2)+y^2$ and on the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ so $5(x^2 + y^2)+y^2 = 5+y^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the boundary, you solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}10x=2\lambda x\\12y=2\lambda y\\x^2+y^2=1\end{array}\right.$$It's solutions are $(x,y)=(\pm1,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,\pm1)$. So, see what's the value of your function at these four points.

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm confused if these are the four solutions why was the global minimum then equal to 0? When doing Lagrande we only get four solutions so why was the global min 0?

Comment: @OGK $(0,0)$ is not a point on the circle $x^2 + y^2=1$ though it is a point in the disk $x^2 + y^2\le 1$

Comment: I see, thank you